# И снова запятая перед тире

Tags: пунктуация

А фраза такая: "Все, чего я хотел(,) — это..." Корректор в тексте запятую мне не поставила (изначально ее не было), но у меня сомнения: нужна она тут или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С этим сочетанием запятая + тире (или наоборот) вообще изрядная путаница, обсуждалось неоднократно, ибо формулировки правил оставляют простор для поиска неоднозначностей. Да, собственно, Вы об этом, похоже, и так знаете.

Но здесь, думаю, без запятой - никак. Просто придаточное внутри главного должно быть "закрыто", а тире для этого ну никак не годится. Ну по крайней мере - в данном случае, обобщать поостерегусь.

Другими словами, тире и запятая тут ставятся по разным основаниям и поэтому, скорее всего, не могут "поглощаться" друг другом.

Так что ставьте запятую, во всяком случае её наличие гораздо проще обосновать, чем её отсутствие.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы поставила, чтобы закрыть придаточное.Может, просмотрела корректор. "Все, чего я хотел, — это увидеть, запомнить и т.д.". Уберём придаточное:"Все — это увидеть, запомнить и т.д."Всё- подлежащее и обобщающее слово для однородных сказуемых, тире нужно,а запятые выделяют придаточное, нужны с двух сторон. Однако раньше было мнение учёных, что достаточно одного знака для обозначения выделительной паузы, значит, возможен пропуск запятой или тире. С современной точки зрения запятая нужна, т.к. эти знаки выполняют разные грамматические функции.

Comment: Согласна с Вами, Людмила.

Comment: Я бы тоже поставила!

Answer (score 0):

Запятая, конечно, нужна, так как предложение, бесспорно, сложноподчинённое. Только, думаю, что всё же в роли подлежащего в данном примере будет выступать инфинитив, а слово "всё" - будет сказуемым (увидеть, запомнить и т. д. является чем? всем; увидеть, запомнить  (что такое?) - всё).